# Java Performance Very Slow in Competitive Programming

Tags: algorithm

I've spent about an hour trying to optimize this code, yet it still seems to TLE.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int testCase = sc.nextInt();

    for(int testCaseCount = 0; testCaseCount < testCase; ++testCaseCount) {
        int M = sc.nextInt();
        int R = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[M];

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt() - 1;
            int index = arr[x];
            out.print(index + " ");
            shift(arr, x, index);
        }

        out.println();
    }

    out.close();
}

public static void shift(int[] arr, int x, int pos) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < pos) ++arr[i];
    }

    arr[x] = 0;
}
```

This is the original problem I'm trying to solve https://open.kattis.com/problems/moviecollection. I tried to use a Stack at first however I soon found out that's way too slow. In this version, I made an array which keeps track of the index which the ith movie box is located. When you update a location, it shifts the box you want to move by assigning it's value in the array to 0, and the ones that had a value less than the original value of the box being moved to 0 are incremented by one. This is the fastest solution I can possibly think of, but a feeling tells me binary search can be involved somehow.

Is it me or Java? Is there a better solution?

Any help is highly valued.

Comment: dont use a for loop, use math.   User intergers for Number on left,  number on right. Should be a simple add and subtract equation from there.

Comment: @Jackstine Can you elaborate I don't understand what you mean. I interpret you are saying that in the shift function I should just have another array tracking the left and right of a movie number?

Comment: The time complexity of your solution is `O(m * r)` per test cases. Of course, it's way too much.

Comment: @Imagine Dragons: I would store an increasing sequence number for every movie pushed onto the stack. Then maintain a Fenwick tree with an entry for each sequence number up to `M+R`, storing ones into presently populated leaves and yielding the cumulative sum in logarithmic time.

Comment: @doynax Wow I never thought (or knew) about indexed binary search trees, I guess I'll create an object and sort through index. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: Java will hardly ever be too slow for any competition. I've been participating in Google Code Jam regularly, and Java was never the reason for my failures. It was always my algorithm. Depending on compiler settings, Java can even be faster than C.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I submitted this solution in C++ and it barely passed :( Do you have any resources you can recommend for learning more data structures?

Comment: Typically, these contests can't be solved in a straightforward way, by applying some textbook knowledge. They often need some Heureka moment where you get "The Right Idea". One idea: at any moment in time, the stack consists of blocks with contiguous indexes. Taking out a movie typically splits one of these blocks into two and adds the movie as single-movie block at the top position. So, maintaining a list of blocks instead of your array reduces runtime complexity (but be sure to cover all special cases correctly).

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved just by using math.  example

```
Input
3 3
3 1 1
output
2 1 0
```

You need to keep track of your current position. Then you need to keep track of the middle video (this handels get 1 when current is 3, should return 1).

```
current = 1;
left = numOfVideos;
mid = 0;
for video in selected
     if video > current:
         video - current - mid;
     else if video < current:
         (current - mid) - video;
     else:
         0;
     current = video;
     if current == left || current == 0:
          mid = 0
     else:
          mid = 1;
```

If the mid part does not work, keep mid at 1. Assuming you can take off any stack at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try to understand it :)

Comment: What are you assigning the value to for video - current - mid? Why keep track of the middle?

Comment: @Jackstine: I must confess that I also do not quite follow you. I gather you are doing a binary search of some sort, but how is the search list to be maintained upon removal without spending linear time on the operation?

Comment: You need to take care of the middle, if you are at video 3, then you know that to get to video 1 you need only take video 2 off.  To get back to video 2, you do 2 - 1 - 1  (video - current - mid) which is 0 moves, cause its on the left stack.  But if you need to go to video 3, then you need to move 3 - 1 - 1 = 1 move.